# Deploy AWS Elasticsearch with OpenDistro via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, terraform, elasticsearch-opendistro

could you please tell me how i can deploy AWS Elasticsearch with OpenDistro authentication via Terraform code? Or it's a new feature and Terraform still doesn't support it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/phillbaker/terraform-provider-elasticsearch/issues/20 ?

Comment: Are you wanting to use the AWS manged Elasticsearch service? Or run it on EC2 or some other platform? What have you tried or read up on so far?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, i'm wanting to use the AWS manged Elasticsearch service

Comment: This already runs OpenDistro for recent Elasticsearch versions as mentioned in https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/faqs/#Open_Distro_for_Elasticsearch. It's not easy to see which version of Open Distro it's running though because features from Open Distro that are in very recent versions of ES and not supported in the version map shown at https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/version-history/ are available in AWS ES (such as Index State Management which should be in 1.3.0/7.3.2 but clusters running ES7.0+ have access to this and AWS ES doesn't yet offer ES 7.3.

Comment: AWS ES tends to lag behind features released on Open Distro but only by a few months. For example, KNN was added to Open Distro on 10th February and then available in AWS ES on 3rd March (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/03/build-k-nearest-neighbor-similarity-search-engine-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service/)

Comment: So the answer is just to create an `aws_elasticsearch_domain` resource with a recent version and that should give you Open Distro features automatically. Terraform doesn't need to do anything to support that.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, many thanks for the documentation, i hope that it will help me.
Just now i created AWS Elasticsearch service under VPC, but OpenDistro feature don't activated automatically. Due it i search terraform code that will be activate this feature, but code for activating OpenDistro doesn't exist.
Could you please provide solution how I should activate this feature?

p.s. one solution - it's create manually AWS Elasticsearch service with OpenDistro feature :-(

Comment: I want to add HTTP basic authentication for AWS Kibana.
Was installed AWS Elasticsearch service(version 7.4 - latest)

Comment: @ydaetskcoR
"I think this is configured at the Elasticsearch level (eg via the UI or the Elasticsearch API) rather than at the AWS Elasticsearch service level so I don't think this provider can help here."
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/12054